# Biblatex: some items of the bibliography printed, some no

Tags: biblatex

I divided my bibliography into manuscripts and printed sources (this one encompassing studies and general bibliography). The bib file is the same but I have selected the titles for each division via keyword:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sigla9nov21.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{series}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{number}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
\begin{document}
\part{Introduction}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword={manuscripta},title={Manuscripts}]
\nocite{Castel-Branco1586}
\printbibliography[keyword={secundaria},title={Printed sources and studies}]
\nocite{Berggren2000}
\nocite{allen1963legend}

\nocite{Taborda1986}
\nocite{zurarabourdon1994}
\part{Some content}
\end{document}
```

The three first items were printed the last two weren't. The bibtex entries in the bib file are:

```
@Manuscript{Castel-Branco1586,
  author    = {Castel-Branco, António de},
  title     = {Quaestiones alique supra Logicam Aristotelis tradite a sapientissimo Antonio de Castelo Brãquo anno Domini 1586\textsuperscript{o} biduo à calendis nouêbris},
  year      = {1586},
  keywords  = {manuscripta},
  library   = {Biblioteca Nacional de Portugal},
  shelfmark = {5053},
}



@Book{allen1963legend,
  author    = {Allen, Don Cameron},
  title     = {The Legend of Noah: Renaissance Rationalism in Art, Science, and Letters},
  year      = {1963},
  series    = {Illini books},
  number    = {v. 33, nos. 3-4},
  publisher = {University of Illinois Press},
  isbn      = {9780252725166},
  url       = {https://books.google.pt/books?id=D8MNAQAAIAAJ},
  keywords  = {Bíblia (interpretação séc. XVI), Noé, Génesis, secundaria},
}

@Book{Berggren2000,
  author        = {J. Lennart Berggren and Alexander Jones},
  title         = {Ptolemy's geography: and annotated translation of the theoretical chapters},
  year          = {2000},
  publisher     = {Princeton University Press},
  
  address       = {Princeton and Oxford},
  keywords      = {secundaria},
}


@Book{zurarabourdon1994,
  author        = {Zurara, Gomes Eanes},
  title         = {Chronique de Guinée (1453), traduite et annotée par Léon Bourdon},
  year          = {1994},
  publisher     = {Editions Chandeigne},
  
  address       = {Paris},
  ignoresseries = {Magellane},
  keywords      = {historiografia (séc. XV -- descobrimentos -- secundaria},
}

@Book{Taborda1986,
  author        = {José Taborda},
  title         = {Os astrolábios planisféricos: uma maravilha da geometria},
  year          = {1986},
  publisher     = {[s.n.]},
  
  address       = {Lisboa},
  keywords      = {astrolábio --- secundaria},
}
```

Comment: It seems you have provided only one of the bibtex entries in your example (the first one cited), please provide the others as well.

Comment: You're right. I've just added the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the two entries affected, you have used sequences of dashes (`---`) to separate different keywords.
These characters are not recognized as a valid separator for the field `keywords` by Bib(La)Tex. Hence, the whole content of the field is parsed as one keyword, and the command `\printbibliography[keyword={secundaria}]` cannot get those entries.

Use a comma instead:

```
keywords      = {historiografia (séc. XV, descobrimentos, secundaria}
```

From §2.2.1 of the biblatex documentation:

> - **Separated value fields** A separated list of literal values. Examples are the `keywords` and `options` fields. The separator can be configured to be any Perl regular expression via the `xsvsep` option which defaults to the usual BibTeX comma surrounded by optional whitespace.

Comment: Just for curiosity: I was led into putting dashes by the catalogue of the Cambridge Library, which uses them in their bibtex files (I got many of the references from there).

Comment: @Sintram: I see. Maybe they have a custom bibtex style to go with that, that recognizes the separator...

Comment: After I removed the dashes the file didn't compile because Lualatex kept complaining about a missing $ (mathematical environment). The issue had to do with urls in the files, now retrieved by biblatex (once the dashes had been removed), that had underscores. I solved adding ignore to the field url.

Comment: @Sintram: Have you imported pkg `hyperref` or `url`? IIRC, they should take care of underscores. Don't throw those URLs out with the bath water! :)

Comment: another good advice. I'll take notice.